# My program won't allow me to call a method from a different class

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-construction, loops

I'm trying to create an android program. The program works like this, a user enters the number of dice he wants to throw and the program does it. My curly brace are all over the place and I don't were to add or remove them. My while statement I use to control input verification, does not work.

Can you help fight my curly braces and fix my while statement.

Here how my program looks like

http://img232.imageshack.us/i/alphascreen.png/

package com.warhammerdicerrolleralpha;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class myMain extends Activity 
{

EditText enternumberofdice;

ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
{
    i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
}
private int myFaceValue;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public int roll() 
{
    int val = (int) (6 * Math.random() + 1); // Range 1-6
    setValue(val);
    return val;
}

int myNum = 0;

{
    try 
        {
            myNum = Integer.parseInt(enternumberofdice.getText().toString());
        } 
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe) 
        {
            enternumberofdice.setText("Does not work");
        } 
}

public int getValue() 
{
    return myFaceValue;
}

public void setValue(int myFaceValue) 
    {
        this.myFaceValue = myFaceValue;

    }
        {  

        switch (myFaceValue)
        {
            case 5: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefive);
            break;
            case 1: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.diceone);
                break;
            case 3: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicethree);
                break;
            case 2: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicetwo);
                break;
            case 4: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicefour);
                break;
            case 6: 
                i.setImageResource(R.drawable.dicesix);
                break;

        }     

    Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text4);

    enternumberofdice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enternumberofdice);


buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                while (myNum  > 0 )
                {

                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    textGenerateNumber.setText(String.valueOf(enternumberofdice));
                    roll();
                    myNum  --;
                }
            }

       });      
}

}

Comment: Does any one have advice to fix my placement of curly braces. I didn't know what's wrong my curly braces. However eclipse says my curly braces are wrong.

Comment: Did you finish the [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)? I might be mistaken, but it looks like you missed some of the basics of Java.

Comment: If Eclipse is flagging an error with your braces then they mustn't be paired correctly. Have you looked closely to make sure you're closing each opened brace properly at the right place?

Comment: I look closely at my braces and I don't see anything missing. I was hoping that maybe someone sees it different and can tell me.

Comment: Ishtar I'm college student learning Java. Your help would be greatly needed.

Comment: Unlike in JavaScript (or some other languages you might have used earlier), functions (called methods in Object Oriented languages) are not first class members so methods cannot be nested (nor can they be returned or assigned to variables). Unlike in C++, all your methods in Java *must* be members of a class (which means they cannot be written outside the closing `{` of a class. Your `onCreate()` method has no matching closing brace. You also have a bunch of other blocks of code that are not inside any method.

Comment: Well, you should really be beginning with the basics then instead of jumping the gun - it will save you a lot of frustration. Do go through the Java tutorials that Ishtar linked to above.

Comment: Okay I'll make those changes.

Comment: I've made some changes, but eclipse says I need to add more curly braces. I don't know were??.

Comment: That wasn't the answer, it was just one observation. Your code doesn't have a simple fix - so unfortunately, you'll need to put some effort into actually understanding what it is that you're coding.

Comment: I'm trying to fix my curly braces, but when I make one change I get another error. I fix most of curly braces on the top, but get curly braces errors on the bottom.?

Comment: Perhaps you should learn more Java before doing Android development. Curly braces are no problem for someone who knows basic Java. If you're having trouble with them, you'll encounter much bigger problems down the line.

Comment: I've fixed all my curly braces. The next error I'm getting is for my while statement. The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) EditText, int.

Comment: If you edited the question because your first question is answered, but now you have a new question, then ask a new question and focus on the new problem you have.  That'll make this question better and your new question better.  win-win!

Comment: Especially since you accepted an answer already, you probably will not get an answer to your new question on this question -- ask a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems I notice:

1) It looks to me like your OnCreate() method doesn't have closing brackets.

2) Remove the } right after this line: `this.myFaceValue = myFaceValue;` and add a } in place of the `// NOT WORKING` line.

Comment: I've edited my post and closing brackets are no longer my problem. Eclipse is not letting me use > operator in my while statement.

Answer (score 1):

A simple "trick" for figuring out where the missing braces ought to go is to use Eclipse's "correct indentation" function.  The indentation will give you clues as to where you need to insert or remove braces.

---

The problem with the '>' operator is that `enternumberofdice` is not a primitive number type.  It is of type `EditText`; i.e. a text entry widget.

Hint: you have to extract the "value" from the widget as text (i.e. a String), then convert the text to a primitive number.

Comment: I'm trying to fix my curly braces, but when I make one change I get another error.

Comment: 1) Look in the menus.  (I don't have a copy of Eclipse I can run right now).  2) Just keep going until you have fixed them.

Comment: I fix them my curly braces mistake. I update my post, I'm having a problem with my while statement. I need to convert EditText into int.